# Aligning div css properties

Tags: jquery, css

```
      <form>         
            <div id="data" name="data" class='checkbox' style='overflow:auto;width:30%;border:1px solid #ccc;height:550px;margin-left:10px;display:inline;'></div>
                <div name="r_data" id="r_data" > </div>
       </form>
```

In the above i populate the data dynamically from jquery. What should be the second div's property? So that the first and second div appear one beside each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches depending on the exact layout you want.  For example you can float the left div:

```
#data { float: left; }
```

And the right would bud up against it (probably what you want since it has a width set).

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fRzQs/).

The alternative is to float the right div to the right with a `style="float: right;"` or `#r_data { float: right }`, but with lack of wide-enough content, this would leave white-space in the middle, so I thought this is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>         
  <div id="data" name="data" class='checkbox' style='overflow:auto;width:30%;border:1px solid #ccc;height:550px;margin-left:10px;display:inline;float:left;'></div>
  <div name="r_data" id="r_data" style="float:left"> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery to do this? justy after populating the data div, move the r_data into data div like this:

```
$('#data').html('some content for data field').next().appendTo('#data');
```

Comment: you can also use prependTo if you want r_data at the beginning of data field.

Comment: I'm not following...this wouldn't solve anything, he wants them *beside* each other, moving it inside just created a block element inside and the content still won't be beside each other, it'll just push down inside the other `<div>` now.

Also, what happens on the next load, where since it's inside he now just blew away the `#r_data` div? :)

Answer (score 0):

use the propery `style="float:left"`